# How to go to next Activity by pass value to intent from AlertDialog?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-alertdialog

I wanna go back to `Place.class` which shows full information of a place.. now I am able to go back to the `Place` activity but the information only shows `title` and `address`.. I think it might happened in `onTab` method. It has only 2 things that was put to the intent....

```
intent.putExtra(Constants.COL_TITLE, oi.getTitle());
intent.putExtra(Constants.COL_ADDRESS, oi.getSnippet());
```

If I wanna put other field i.e. `content` `phone` etc. How do I put data from database to this intent?

```
intent.putExtra(Constants.COL_CON, ..........);
```

Thank you for your help

I have 3 Class here

`xxx.class`

```
public class xxx extends MapActivity {

    MapView mapView;
    MapController mapController;
    private static MyDB mDbHelper;
    private Cursor c;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.aboutcm);

        mDbHelper = new MyDB(this);
        mDbHelper.createDatabase();
        mDbHelper.open();
        c = mDbHelper.getAttraction();

        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapController = mapView.getController();
        Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.map_pin_3);
        List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
        PlaceItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay = new PlaceItemizedOverlay(drawable, this);


        mapController.setZoom(13);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);


        c.moveToFirst(); 
        do {

            String title = c.getString(c
                    .getColumnIndex(Constants.COL_TITLE));
            String address = c.getString(c
                    .getColumnIndex(Constants.COL_ADDRESS));
            String content = c.getString(c
                    .getColumnIndex(Constants.COL_CONTENT));
            int latitude = (int) (c.getDouble(c
                    .getColumnIndex(Constants.COL_LA)) * 1E6);
            int longitude = (int) (c.getDouble(c
                    .getColumnIndex(Constants.COL_LONG)) * 1E6);


            itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(new OverlayItem(new GeoPoint(latitude, longitude), title,
                    address));
            mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);

        } while (c.moveToNext());
        mDbHelper.close();

    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

}
```

---

`PlaceItemizedOverlay.class`

```
public class PlaceItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {

    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<OverlayItem> mOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();

    public PlaceItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Context context)
    {
        super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
        mContext = context;
    }
    public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {
        mOverlays.add(overlay);
        populate();
    }

    @Override
    protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mOverlays.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mOverlays.size();    }


    @Override
    protected boolean onTap(int index) {

      final OverlayItem oi = mOverlays.get(index);
      AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
      dialog.setTitle(oi.getTitle());
      dialog.setMessage(oi.getSnippet());
      dialog.setNegativeButton("Back", null);
      dialog.setPositiveButton("See More Detail", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
              Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, Place.class);
                intent.putExtra(Constants.COL_TITLE, oi.getTitle());
                intent.putExtra(Constants.COL_ADDRESS, oi.getSnippet());
                mContext.startActivity(intent); 
      }});
      dialog.show();
      return true;

    }


}
```

Comment: In which activity are you creating the AlertDialog? and you can create your own key for putExtra. Ex: intent.putExtra("content", content), then in the receiving activity: intent.getStringExtra("content"); See goo.gl/VbYcd

Comment: xxx Activity which extend MapActiviy.. as you see i create AlertDialog at `onTab` method in PlaceItemizedOverlay.class  By the way, intent.putExtra("content", content) should stay onTab method or outside. And i also use this line Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, Place.class); but it seem like mContext has only 2 value from PlaceItemizedOverlay constructor which are title and address... how about others? i try many ways...i'm confuse which value should i put in the second content..("content", ?????) i try to put i.putExtra("content", c.getColumnIndex("content")); But, it's not work

Comment: Thannksss you so much , finally i got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you want to pass the String "123456789" from xxx Activity to Place.class. Then you would use `intent.putExtra("content", "123456789")` and then in Place.class `intent.getStringExtra("content")` would return "123456789"

> Could i declare.... Intent i = new Intent(??????, Place.class); } And
>   what should i put into ??????

You could do one of three things. First, my preferred method is in the class body declare:

```
Context context;
```

And then in `onCreate(...)` declare:

```
context = this;
```

and then you could do:

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, Place.class);
```

Secondly, you could declare:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Place.class);
```

Thirdly, in your class body you could declare:

```
Intent i;
```

Then in `onCreate(...)`:

```
i = new Intent(this, Place.class);
```

WIth the third method you would then be able to use `startActivity(i)` in the alertDialog

Comment: The last thing, i want to know.. if i create dialog.setPositiveButton("See More Detail", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {...}  and i @Override
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {...Could i declare.... Intent i = new Intent(??????, Place.class); } And what should i put into ??????... If u see from the above code.. i cannot put (xxx.this, Place.class) or (mContext, Place.class) How should i do to get the exactly result of each place? Thanks you so much

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple intent passing program: from Main Intent to Second Intent

```
public void nextButtonOnClick(View arg0)
    {
        Intent intent=(new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Modify in XML file:

```
android:onClick="nextButtonOnClick"
```